# Numerical sort in shell when each line does not begin with number

Tags: linux, shell, posix

I have this file.

```
$ cat foo.txt
foo 1
foo 12
foo 110
foo 15
foo 120
```

I want to sort this file numerically. But I am unable to do so with the `sort -n` command.

```
$ sort -n foo.txt
foo 1
foo 110
foo 12
foo 120
foo 15
```

The output I expect is this.

```
foo 1
foo 12
foo 15
foo 110
foo 120
```

I have two questions.

1. Why does `sort -n` not sort the file numerically? When it finds two lines `foo 12` and `foo 110`, the initial part `foo` are same in both, so it would be forced to compare `12` and `110` numerically and decide that `12` comes before `110` but as we can see in the output, this is not the case. Why?
2. How can I achieve the numerical sort, i.e. the expected output, in Unix/Linux. I am open to non-POSIX commands and options but it would be ideal to have something that works in a POSIX shell or system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sort -nk2 foo.txt
foo 1
foo 12
foo 15
foo 110
foo 120
```

From the sort man page:

> -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>   start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)

As for an answer to the first part of your question: I don't know for sure (i.e., I don't find it explicitly mentioned), but sort works by fields, with the default separator set to whitespace. So by default, it sorts on the first field only, and ignores the other fields. If you would try and combine both fields, e.g. by using `-t` and setting it to some non-used character (`-t$`), `-n` sorts on numerical *string* value, which would be alphabetical (since `foo` simply isn't a number). Thus, `foo 110` would still come before `foo 12`.